# Java For Loop with ImageIcon

Tags: java, image, loops, for-loop, nullpointerexception

Can anyone help me solve this?

```
imagePanel = new JPanel();
label = new JLabel();

for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
{
   label.setIcon(image[i]);
   imagePanel.add(label);
}
```

When using this it gives me the errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException...

    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
    at assignment.Furniture_System.<init>(Furniture_System.java:55)
    at assignment.Furniture_System.main(Furniture_System.java:113)
```

I suppose I should explain that I call this for loop in a void function that implements in a class constructor. That constructor is called in the main program.

And the variable array image is shown here:

```
private ImageIcon image[] = 

        {
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\1.jpg"), 
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\2.jpg"), 
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\3.jpg"),
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\4.jpg"), 
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\5.jpg"), 
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\6.jpg"),
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\7.jpg"), 
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\8.jpg"), 
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\9.jpg"), 
            new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\10.jpg"), 
        };
```

All I am trying to do is cycle through the array, set and display the images as the cycle goes through.

Below is the whole program to make it easier to fix:

```
    private ImageIcon image[] = 
    {
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\1.jpg"), 
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\2.jpg"), 
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\3.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\4.jpg"), 
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\5.jpg"), 
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\6.jpg"),
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\7.jpg"), 
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\8.jpg"), 
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\9.jpg"), 
        new ImageIcon ("C:\\Users\\James\\Pictures\\Java\\10.jpg") 
    };

    private JLabel label;

    private JLabel sofaImageLabel;
    private JLabel armchairImageLabel;
    private JLabel cDeskImageLabel;
    private JLabel cTableImageLabel;
    private JLabel tvStandImageLabel;
    private JLabel cushionImageLabel;
    private JLabel bedImageLabel;
    private JLabel mattressImageLabel;
    private JLabel duvetImageLabel;
    private JLabel pillowImageLabel;

    private JPanel buttonPanel;
    private JPanel imagePanel;

    private JButton button;

    public Furniture_System()
    {
        setTitle("Furniture Management System");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        buildImagePanel();
        // buildButtonPanel();

        add(imagePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);   
    }

    private void buildImagePanel()
    {
        imagePanel = new JPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            label = new JLabel();
            label.setIcon(image[i]);
            imagePanel.add(label);
        }
    }

       private void buildButtonPanel()
       {
          buttonPanel = new JPanel();

          button = new JButton("Get Image");

          button.addActionListener(new chooseFileButton());
          buttonPanel.add(button);
       }

       private class chooseFileButton implements ActionListener
       {

          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
        /*    String filename = null;

            JFileChooser fileChosen = new JFileChooser();
            int status = fileChosen.showOpenDialog(null);

            if (status == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                File selectedFile = fileChosen.getSelectedFile();
                filename = selectedFile.getPath();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You selected "  + filename);
            }

            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(filename);
            sofaImageLabel.setIcon(image);
            sofaImageLabel.setText(null);
            pack(); */
          }
       }

    public static void main(String[] args)
       {
          new Furniture_System();
       }

}
```

Comment: I can't see the reason for the NPE just yet, but you appear to be adding the same JLabel multiple times to your GUI, and that won't work. You can add a component to the GUI only once. Perhaps you meant to create a new JLabel ***inside*** of the for loop.

Comment: Okay, I put the label = new JLabel(); inside the loop so it would refresh with every iteration. Still no luck.

Comment: Can you show us the whole file?  I feel like there's a control flow problem here that we can't see

Comment: In `Furniture_System.java` file what do you have as lines # **113** and **55**?

Comment: 55 is       add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);            113 is      new Furniture_System();

Comment: `buttonPanel` is probably null, then.

Comment: Have you checked buttonPanel? It may not be instantiated and hence throwing NPE

Comment: You commented out the method call that created the button panel, `buildButtonPanel();`, and this is causing your NPE, and then in your original question showed us code completely irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Well how was I supposed to know the method I wasnt using was causing the problem?

Comment: Because you need to look at the lines that the NPE is pointing you to.

Comment: Thanks everyone it works now :D sorta... but Im sure I can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

Any component can have only one parent container, and not be reused.
So the code must be:

```
for (ImageIcon img : image)
{
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(img);
    imagePanel.add(label);
}
```

Though I would look in Furniture_System.java at line 55 (in the constructor) what could be an access to null. Like above maybe `imagePanel` being null.

Comment: Yep that fixed it, didnt realise as I wasnt using it! thanks man.